# .getElementById returning undefined in .createTextNode

Tags: javascript, html

I've got this real simple code here:

```
<input type="text" id="haha"></input>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>


<script>
    var sth = document.getElementById("haha").value;

    function myFunction() {
        var h = document.createElement("p");
        var t = document.createTextNode("Hello" + sth.value);
        h.appendChild(t);
        document.body.appendChild(h);
    }
</script>
```

and everything's working fine except it's returning me Helloundefined, not the value I've inputted into the textbox. I've tried all kinds of other stuff too but it will return either nothing or `[object HTMLInputElement]`. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `sth` to the element's value:

```
var sth = document.getElementById("haha").value;
```

so `sth` is a string.  Then, you try to get the (non-existent) `value` property of that string:

```
var t = document.createTextNode("Hello" + sth.value);
```

Instead, set `sth` to the element itself:

```
var sth = document.getElementById("haha");
```

```js
var sth = document.getElementById("haha");

function myFunction() {
  var h = document.createElement("p");
  var t = document.createTextNode("Hello " + sth.value);
  h.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(h);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="haha"></input>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```